# How to make my pop-up disappear after 3 sec

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, popup

So I would like to make this pop-up disappear after 3 seconds. I have tried the delay query that most recommend but I must be doing something wrong because every time I add it in something glitchy starts happening with other parts of my webpage. I am novice when it comes to java.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#thover").click(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut();
    $("#tpopup").fadeOut();
 });
  
  
  $("#tclose").click(function(){
  $("#thover").fadeOut();
    $("#tpopup").fadeOut();
 });
  
});
 </script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
#thover{
  position:fixed;
  background:#000;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity: .6
}
 
#tpopup{
  position:absolute;
  width:600px;
  height:280px;
  background:#fff;
  left:50%;
  top:97%;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:0px 0;
  margin-left:-320px; /* width/2 + padding-left */
  margin-top:-150px; /* height/2 + padding-top */
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 #000;
}
#tclose{
  position:absolute;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  right:-15px;
  top:-15px;
  border-radius:50%;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:8px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:'Arial Black', Arial, sans-serif;
  cursor:pointer;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 #000;
}</style>
```

```html
<div id="thover">
 &nbsp;</div>
<div id="tpopup">
 <img src="" /><img alt="http://www.raffles-american-school.edu.my/usr/pagesub.aspx?pgid=62" src="/data/cms/images/boarding_pop_up_3(1).jpg" style="width: 600px; height: 280px;" />
 <div id="tclose">
  X</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a separate function for this, called `closePopup` then invoke it in relevant click function along with invoke it when the page has been loaded for 3 seconds.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  function closePopup(){
  $("#thover").fadeOut();
    $("#tpopup").fadeOut();
 }
  
  $("#thover").click(closePopup); 
  $("#tclose").click(closePopup);
  
  setTimeout(closePopup,3000);
  
});
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
#thover{
  position:fixed;
  background:#000;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity: .6
}
 
#tpopup{
  position:absolute;
  width:600px;
  height:280px;
  background:#fff;
  left:50%;
  top:97%;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:0px 0;
  margin-left:-320px; /* width/2 + padding-left */
  margin-top:-150px; /* height/2 + padding-top */
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 #000;
}
#tclose{
  position:absolute;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  right:-15px;
  top:-15px;
  border-radius:50%;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:8px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:'Arial Black', Arial, sans-serif;
  cursor:pointer;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 #000;
}</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thover">
 &nbsp;</div>
<div id="tpopup">
 <img src="" /><img alt="http://www.raffles-american-school.edu.my/usr/pagesub.aspx?pgid=62" src="/data/cms/images/boarding_pop_up_3(1).jpg" style="width: 600px; height: 280px;" />
 <div id="tclose">
  X</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! the second solution worked beautifuly

Answer (score 1):

This code will execute after 3 seconds:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#tpopup").fadeOut();
},3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at the end of the script, and it should work:

```
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $("#thover").fadeOut();
      $("#tpopup").fadeOut()}, 3000);
```